# Service cannot be injected to controller in Angular.js project

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a simple single page app with Angular. I am just trying to connect a custom service to the main controller at the moment. It simply returns the length of a string to the controller.

This is from my app.js:

```
angular
  .module('weatherApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

This is my main controller:

```
angular.module('weatherApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'weatherService', function ($scope, weatherService) {
$scope.name = weatherService.name;

$scope.$watch('name', function() {
  weatherService.name = $scope.name;
});

$log.log(weatherService.name);
$log.log(weatherService.namelength());


}]);
```

And this is the service:

```
angular.module('weatherApp')
  .service('weatherService', function () {
var self = this
this.name = 'Moscow weather';

this.namelength = function() {

  return self.name.length;

};
});
```

Error in the browser debugger:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: weatherServiceProvider <-     weatherService <- MainCtrl
```

Comment: You probably forgot to add a <script> tag in the HTML page for the service.

Comment: Thank you that was very silly of me.